# Ruby on Rails action working but tests fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a project for my bootcamp and I cannot fathom why the tests are failing but the action correctly works. The tests:

```
describe "POST create" do
 it "increases the number of topics by 1" do
   expect{ post :create, {topic: {name: RandomData.random_sentence, description: RandomData.random_paragraph}}}.to change(Topic,:count).by(1)
 end

 it "assigns Topic.last to @topic" do
   post :create, {topic: {name: RandomData.random_sentence, description: RandomData.random_paragraph}}
   expect(assigns(:topic)).to eq Topic.last
 end

 it "redirects to the new topic" do
   post :create, {topic: {name: RandomData.random_sentence, description: RandomData.random_paragraph}}
   expect(response).to redirect_to Topic.last
 end
end
```

The create action:

```
 def create
   @topic = Topic.new
   @topic.name = params[:topic][:name]
   @topic.description = params[:topic][:description]
   @topic.public = params[:topic][:public]

   if @topic.save
     redirect_to @topic, notice: "Topic was saved successfully."
   else
     flash.now[:alert] = "Error creating topic. Please try again."
     render :new
   end
 end
```

I check my tests:

```
rspec spec/controllers/topics_controller_spec.rb -e 'POST create'
```

I get three failures.

```
Failures:
1) TopicsController POST create increases the number of topics by 1
 Failure/Error: expect{ post :create, {topic: {name: RandomData.random_sentence, description: RandomData.random_paragraph }}}.to change(Topic, :count).by(1)

 ArgumentError:
   unknown keyword: topic
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.2/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.2/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
 # ./spec/controllers/topics_controller_spec.rb:54:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/controllers/topics_controller_spec.rb:54:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) TopicsController POST create assigns Topic.last to @topic
 Failure/Error: post :create, {topic: {name: RandomData.random_sentence, description: RandomData.random_paragraph}}

 ArgumentError:
   unknown keyword: topic
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.2/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.2/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
 # ./spec/controllers/topics_controller_spec.rb:58:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) TopicsController POST create redirects to new topic
 Failure/Error: post :create, {topic: {name: RandomData.random_sentence, description: RandomData.random_paragraph}}

 ArgumentError:
   unknown keyword: topic
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.2/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.2/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
 # ./spec/controllers/topics_controller_spec.rb:63:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02654 seconds (files took 2.16 seconds to load)
3 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:
rspec ./spec/controllers/topics_controller_spec.rb:53 # TopicsController POST create increases the number of topics by 1
rspec ./spec/controllers/topics_controller_spec.rb:57 # TopicsController POST create assigns Topic.last to @topic
rspec ./spec/controllers/topics_controller_spec.rb:62 # TopicsController POST create redirects to new topic
```

The error is telling me that there is an issue with the unknown keyword "topic" yet that keyword works fine in the other 7 tests in my topics_controller_spec.rb file. I have been staring at this for over an hour and cannot fathom for the life of me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you picked up an old example.

You would need to add `params` with the params key. Try this

```
describe "POST create" do
  it "increases the number of topics by 1" do
    expect{ post :create, params: {topic: ...} }.to change(Topic,:count).by(1)
  end
end
```